# Fallo al llamar a función en Pyhon

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo esta pequeña fracción del código que no consigo hacer que funcione:

```py
from random import choices 
""" Importa choices para generar opciones aleatorios con una probabilidad específica. """

class Dados_jugador:
    def __init__(self, eleccion=None):
        if eleccion == None:
            self.tirar_dado()
        else:
            pass

    def tirar_dado(self):
        self.caras = [self.guerrero, self.mago, self.templario, self.ladron, self.pergamino, self.campeon]
        cara = choices(self.caras, weights=[2,2,2,2,1,1], k=1)
        cara()

    def guerrero(self):
        self.personaje = "Guerrero"
        self.color = "verde"

    def mago(self):
        self.personaje = "mago"
        self.color = "azul"

    def templario(self):
        self.personaje = "Templario"
        self.color = "blanco"

    def ladron(self):
        self.personaje = "Ladrón"
        self.color = "morado"

    def pergamino(self):
        self.personaje = "Pergamino"
        self.color = "naranja"

    def campeon(self):
        self.personaje = "Campeón"
        self.color = "amarillo"

a = Dados_jugador()

print(a.personaje)
```

La idea es que aleatoriamente (aunque también tengo que hacer que se pueda escoger una opción específica) obtengas el valor del personaje y el color. Pensé en hacerlo con diccionario, con clases apartes, con métodos... Pero no consigo aclararme. Por ahora lo intentaré con métodos, pero me da un error al ejecutar el código, algo así como que las listas no son llamabes

Comment: `random.choices` retorna una lista de la longitud de `k` siempre (aunque `k` sea 1), para obtener el elemento (referencia al método) debes indizar sobre ella: `cara[0]()`, en caso contrario estás intentando llamar a un objeto `list`.

Comment: Por cierto no hagas `if eleccion == None:`, lo correcto es `if eleccion is None:`.

Comment: Gracias!

El else es porque habrá una condición si no se cumple el elección.